# (VBA) For Loop That Clears Cells of Variable Range

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to create a Subroutine that clears out cell contents if the cells meet certain parameters. I thought this would be fairly straightforward but it seems like it's more complicated than I thought.

Here are the requirements:

a) the function needs to start by selecting cell E4 through I4

b) Everything in the cells must be cleared unless the cells are COLORED.

c) with each iteration the row NUMBER goes up, columns stay the same.

I have attached the code I have written, and also the "old code" which I have been tasked with updating. As you can see, I am trying to make the new code more intelligent than the old code (the old code clears out a static range of cells).

I have tried using a few different loop statements, every time getting some sort of error. With this code, I do not get an error (great!), but it does not appear to do anything to the target worksheet. All the cells are still filled with data after running this :(

```
Sub Clear ()

    target = ActiveSheet.Name  ' Day Sheet
    Sheets(target).Select
    For counter = 4 To 1000
        If Range("e" & counter, "i" & counter).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlColorIndexNone Then
            Range("e" & counter, "i" & counter).ClearContents
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub

'This is the OLD CODE, that has been proven to work:

Sub Clear()
'
    target = ActiveSheet.Name  ' Day Sheet
    Sheets(target).Select
    Range("c4:i29").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I expected the new code to work, or perhaps clear out more rows than required, but it seems to do nothing. The screen flashes for a split second, so I know the code runs, but with no actual effect. Any help is welcome and very much appreciated!!!!

Comment: You only want to clear non colored cells? Or you want to clear the entire range IF none are colored? Pretty much asking if the rule should apply individually to each cell here

Comment: You have an `Exit For` that just cancels the whole iteration

Comment: @urdearboy actually now that you  mention it, once the script hits the first colored cell the entire operation can stop. It doesn't need to go further.

Comment: @JvdV I tried taking out the Exit For as you mentioned, I get no errors but same result. Nothing has actually been cleared :(

Comment: @urdearboy - that's equivalent to what OP is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here is a possible solution (assuming you need to empty all cells that are not colored):

```
Sub Test()

Application.FindFormat.Clear
Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = xlColorIndexNone

With Sheet1 'Replace with your Sheet's CodeName
    .Range("E4:I1000").Replace What:="*", Replacement:="", SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=False
End With

End Sub
```

---

Maybe you want to `Exit For` by design once you hit your first colored cells. You currently just check a full range from column E-I against `xlColorIndexNone`. And only when all these are different, you'll satisfy your check and it will continue to `ClearContents`. I guess this is why currently your code is "not working" (it actually is working) since it will probably never be true. Also see that your `Exit For` would stop the iteration once the above statement would ever be true.

Comment: Good stuff anyway, Findformat is much under-used, even if I have found it erratic on occasion.

Comment: Yes it doesn't always seem to detect the settings. `Range("A1, A10")` will select only the 2 cells.

Comment: @BigBen - yes, I thought udearboy was confused by the comma thing.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks so much! This solution works perfectly. Problem solved. Cheers everyone for the help!!! :)